# Is this normal hard drive noise?

Tags: hard-drive

I recently replaced my PC's hard drive with a [Hitachi GST Deskstar 7K2000 HDS722020ALA330](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822145298) and it makes so much noise that I want to replace it again. I re-read the reviews for this drive expecting to see people complaining about the noise but I didn't see much in that regard, this makes me wonder.... is this normal?

Please listen to the audio in the following YouTube video. MovieMaker made my add a video or image so I grabbed a photo that was on my desktop. It's a laptop, that is NOT the system I'm talking about.
https://youtu.be/6cglrQouqdo

WMIC reports status:

> OK

CrystalDiskInfo also [claims all is well](http://spireon.d.pr/DM42/4vrOQ7y9)

If this is normal, is there a specification that addresses "operation noise"? How can I purchase a drive that is quiet (without going SSD)?

Answer (score 1):

Not all noises coming from the HDD are signs of a coming failure, so IMO there is no need to worry about, especially since two diagnostic tests from different tool have reported no problems with the hard disk.

If you want though you can take a look at [this KB article](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=rGd5JL) for more information regarding the drive noises.

Hope this helps and feel free to ask any questions you may have. :)